# lineinfile module creating a file if it doesn't exist even I use "create=no"

Tags: ansible, automation, ansible-playbook

```
---
- hosts: testhost
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: change user profile
      copy: src=/tmp/profile dest=/home/test/.bash_profile force=no owner=test group=test
    - name: update bashrc
      copy: src=/tmp/bashrc dest=/home/test/.bashrc owner=test group=test force=no
    - name: add umask to the file
      lineinfile: dest=/home/test/.bashrc create=no line="umask 022" create=no
```

Comment: You should copy-paste the stanza and then add four spaces in front, that way formatting will not be interpreted, it will be easier to read.

Comment: I've put four spaces not three :) And answered the question, too!

Comment: For completeness, what version of Ansible are you using? There have been some bugs (even if [this one](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29893) seems to be the opposite of what you are experiencing).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is the `copy` that is creating the file. That line will not modify a file that already exists (because `force=no`), but will when it doesn't.

Then, the `lineinfile` will make sure that the file contains `umask 022`.

Comment: I've used "when: file.stat.exists" it is not creating if a file exists. But if file has some content its overwriting the whole content with /tmp/bashrc. My intention is to just append only "umask 022" if the file already exists with some content. it should not touch the existing content. (Note: I've register the path with file variable)

Comment: OK -- you should write your intention in your question, it would make it clearer. Your `copy` line should *not* overwrite `/home/test/.bashrc`, that's what `force=no` means, so as written in your question the code should work as intended. There's a double `create=no` in the last line but that shouldn't matter. If it isn't working, try executing it in [debug mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html) to see what is happening.